# SAX handling special characters

Tags: java, sax

I'm trying to parse an XML file with Java and SAX for an android device. I got from the internet and while parsing it I'm getting an ExpatException : not well-formed (invalid token) on the character "é". 
Is there a way to handle those characters without having to change all the specials characters in the xml file?

edit : 
Here is the part of my code writing the file to my SDcard.

```
File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File f = new File(SDCardRoot,"edt.xml");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();


            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }

            fileOutput.close();
```

Here is a part of my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ttss.xsl"?>

<timetable>
<option combined="0" totalweeks="0" showemptydays="0" dayclass="reverse">
<link href="g56065.xml" class="xml">Imprimer</link>
<link href="g56065.pdf" class="pdf">Version PDF</link>
<weeks>Semaines</weeks>
<dates>Dates</dates>
<week>Semaine</week>
<date>Date</date>
<all>Toutes les semaines</all>
<notes>Remarques</notes>
<id>ID</id>
<tag>Champs Libre</tag>
<footer>Publié le 10/09/2011 22:14:28</footer>
... </timetable>
```

here is the parsing code :

```
public class ParserSemaines extends DefaultHandler {
    private final String SEMAINE = "span";
    private final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private ArrayList<Semaine> semaines;
    private boolean inSemaine;
    private Semaine currentSemaine;
    private StringBuffer buffer;
    @Override
    public void processingInstruction(String target, String data) throws SAXException {
        super.processingInstruction(target, data);
    }
    public ParserSemaines() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.startDocument();
        semaines = new ArrayList<Semaine>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(SEMAINE)){
            this.currentSemaine = new Semaine();
            this.currentSemaine.setDate(attributes.getValue("date"));
            this.inSemaine = true;
        }
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)){
            this.currentSemaine.setDescription(buffer.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(SEMAINE)){
            this.semaines.add(currentSemaine);
            this.inSemaine = false;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch,int start, int length) throws SAXException{
        String lecture = new String(ch,start,length);
        if(buffer != null) buffer.append(lecture);
    }

    public ArrayList<Semaine> getData(){
        return semaines;
    }
}
```

here is the code I use to call the parser :

```
SAXParserFactory fabrique = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parseur = null;
        ArrayList<Semaine> semaines = null;
        try {
            parseur = fabrique.newSAXParser();
            DefaultHandler handler = new ParserSemaines();
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"edt.xml");
            parseur.parse(f, handler);  
            semaines = ((ParserSemaines) handler).getData();
        }
```

Ask if any other code parts are required.

After check it appears that the xml file in the SDcard shows "é" as "ï¿½". 
That should be the problem but I don't have any clue why.
I also tried to parse with the URI but it don't change anything I get always the same exception.

Comment: The SAX parser should handle non-ASCII characters without any problem. Show your code, and an example of your XML.

Comment: Sound like either: 1. the XML file was incorrectly encoded, or 2. the XML file was served correctly on the Internet, with its character encoding indicated by HTTP headers, and you lost that information when saving the file locally.

Comment: The code shown just copies the data as raw bytes, and thus can't be confused in any way re XML encoding.  You need to show the parsing code.

Comment: Please add the code where you set up the actual SAX parser (ie, get the parser from the parser factory and call parse()).

Comment: Your parsing code looks fine, which indicates that the server is giving you incorrect content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution. 
Instead of using SAXparder, I use

```
android.util.Xml.parse(InputStream,Xml.Encoding.ISO_8859_1, DefaultHandler);
```

Thanks everyone for all the help you provide me.

Answer (score 1):

> After check it appears that the xml file in the SDcard shows "é" as "ï¿½".

This does indicate an encoding problem.

The code that you posted appears to be a correct byte-by-byte copy from the URL to the file, so the file should represent exactly what you're getting from the URL. Which means that the response from the server may not be in ISO-8859-1.

My next step would be to use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to examine the entire response, paying particular attention to:

- The Content-Type header. If it tells you a different character set, you'll have to pass that information to the parser and/or manually convert it.
- The actual bytes returned. For all you know, *both* the Content-Type and the XML prologue could be lying. If the file is truly ISO-8859-1, then the accented e should have a byte value of 0xE9. If the content is actually UTF-8, there should be the two-byte sequence 0xC3 0xA9 (see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm)). You're showing a three-byte sequence, which doesn't make sense. But it's best to check the source.

Also, verify that you're *not* converting the file to a string before passing it to the SAX parser.

---

For reference: I wrote a minimal program that connects to the OP's URL and passes that connection directly to a minimal SAX parser. It appeared to run without error. I also used a DOM parser, and verified that at least the root element had been parsed correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception
{
   URL url = new URL("http://www.disvu.u-bordeaux1.fr/et/edt_etudiants2/Master/Semestre1/g56065.xml");
   InputStream in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();

   SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
   SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();
   parser.parse(in, new DefaultHandler());
   System.out.println("parse successful");
}
```

Comment: here is the fiddler result, response header : 
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 16:01:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 15:18:40 GMT
ETag: "da80c9-1e634-46611400"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 124468
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/xml

I checked and "é" is effectively 0xE9 in the hex result.

I feel like the only solution i got is changing all "é" to "e" even if it will take some time to process.
Here is the xml file URL : 
http://www.disvu.u-bordeaux1.fr/et/edt_etudiants2/Master/Semestre1/g56065.xml

Comment: @Alexis - I have to admit that I'm stumped. I loaded your link, and sure enough, the content appears to be in ISO-8859-1 encoding. And all of the headers look right. And your code looks right for a simple byte-by-byte copy.

Comment: I find it strange that the file on the SD card is showing different bytes. Are you simply sending it to the terminal, or are you using a hex dump program? If the former, try the latter to verify that the bytes are actually being expanded in the file.

Comment: And is it possible for you to eliminate the copy altogether? The SAX parser will take its input directly from an InputStream.

Comment: First question : I did copy the file to my computer to read it. I'll try to check  bytes when back on my computer. 
I tried to get the xml straight from the URI and it did the same. I called the parser with parser.parse(URI,handler);

Comment: @Alexis - this has been bugging me, so I downloaded the file using wget, and parsed it with a `DefaultHandler`. Didn't see any errors during the parse. Also opened it using a `URLConnection` and again the parse was successful. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Can it be from my download way instead of wget ?

Comment: @Alexis - I don't think so. I edited my post to include a minimal program that appears to parse the file successfully.

Comment: I just reread your question, and saw that you mentioned "ExpatException", which I've never heard of. I assumed that the exception was being thrown from within the SAX parser, but now I'm wondering if it could be from somewhere else in your code. Do you have a stack trace for the exception?

Comment: I don't have any stacktrace (null). I just copy/paste your example and it don't work on my android phone. But running it in a java standard program it does work perfectly on my computer. I don't understand why it doesn't work on an android phone.

Comment: @Alexis - ahhh ... Android no doubt uses a different parser implementation than "standard" Java. Or perhaps manages the URLConnection stream differently. Unfortunately, I don't do any Android work so won't be much help. I suggest retagging the question with "android" in the hope that someone better-qualified will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the encoding. Try changing it to `ISO-8859-1`.

In your xml try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

or, in your code, use:

```
inputSource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: In my xml the encoding is correctly set up. I never uses inputSource, where should I use it ?